# PHP MySQL UPDATE statement not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I have a MySQL database with a table (opendpu) that has multiple columns including columns titled "ECRNUM" and "PE_REQUIRED".

I'm simply trying to **test** this update statement by specifying some values. I get this error:

> Array ( [0] => 42000 [1] => 1064 [2] => You have an error in your
>   SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use near 'DOE WHERE ECRNUM = 81308' at
>   line 1 )

I cannot, for the life of me, figure out what is wrong here. Can anyone help?

```
<?php
  require ('config.php');
 $ecrno = '81308';
 $pe_required = 'JOHN DOE';

while (true) {
try {
    $db = new PDO($dsn, $uname, $pword);
    $db->exec( "SET CHARACTER SET utf8" );
    $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ); 
    $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT, true );
    break;
}
    catch (Exception $e) {
        $db = null;
        $counter++;
        if ($counter == $limit)
            throw $e;
    }
}

$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE opendpu SET PE_REQUIRED = $pe_required WHERE ECRNUM = $ecrno");
$stmt->execute() or die(print_r($stmt->errorInfo(), true));

  ?>
```

.

Comment: Missing quotes maybe?

Comment: It seems you are having a single quote in your data for $pe_required . You could escape it by using [addslashes](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) function . But as you are already using PDO , you should be passing the values a parameters .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your syntax like this [*Enclosed quotes around the variable*]

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE `opendpu` SET PE_REQUIRED = '$pe_required' WHERE ECRNUM = '$ecrno'");
```

Comment: Always a good idea to pass data into statements via string functions and not via the driver. SQL injection is waving at you.

Comment: i dont think single quote is a must for enclosing the php variable while using in sql query.

Comment: Well, this works. But I agree @RishabhRaj I thought with php the quotes were not necessary.

Comment: @bagofmilk, You definitely need input sanitization. Go through the articles on SO.

Comment: Again...guys..this was a quick test. It's not like I'm going to launch this. Of course I needed to bind parameters, but I'm not worried about someone hacking my test file.

Comment: Thats fair enough, but the point is, correct practice using bind_param WOULD have solved your problem and therefore, not taking shortcuts you would not have had the problem in the first place, therefore comments advising you to do so are valid.

Answer (score 3):

+1 for using prepared statements... but (and its a big BUT):

You should never use prepared statements without `bind_param` as this leaves you wide open to SQL injection and negates the benefits of prepared statements.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE opendpu SET PE_REQUIRED=? WHERE ECRNUM=?");
$stmt->bind_param('si', $pe_required, $ecrno);
$stmt->execute() or die(print_r($stmt->errorInfo(), true));
```

Comment: I agree. But this was only to quickly test my statement

Answer (score 0):

Please check with below query

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE opendpu SET PE_REQUIRED = '.$pe_required.' WHERE ECRNUM = '.$ecrno.'");
```